# Is there a way to write a variables name in a bat file using bat?

Tags: batch-file, variables

I'm asking this because I want to make a download file for a simple website IP finder I made. Here is the code so far:

```
@echo off
color 03
SET /P user=Enter the user you are using here: 
echo.>>"C:\Users\%user%\desktop\WebIPFind.bat"
echo @echo off > WebIPFind.bat
echo color 03 >> WebIPFind.bat
echo :loop >> WebIPFind.bat
echo SET /A ip=%ip%+1 >> WebIPFind.bat
echo ECHO IP No. %ip% >> WebIPFind.bat
echo SET /P website=Enter a website URL:  >> WebIPFind.bat
echo ping %website% -l 8 -w 1 -n 1 >> WebIPFind.bat
echo goto :loop >> WebIPFind.bat
```

but when I use this it just replaces the variables with blank spaces. Is there a way to make it so it writes the names of the variables? (I don't need the user variable to be written because that is used to select where to write the bat file)

Comment: I don't really work with `.bat` files but try separating the `set` commands and the `echo` commands maybe? Also, i see that you're not setting the value of `ip` anywhere before you assign it to `ip`..

Comment: the % character is it's own escape character. to output the variable expansion literally, without the variable expanding, which will occur even if the variable is not defined, you need to use: `%%VariableName%%`
  - All that said, it makes little sense to create another batch file from your batch when you could just call a function within the batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your modified sample, like T3RROR explained

```
@echo off
color 03
SET /P user=Enter the user you are using here: 

(
  echo(
  echo @echo off
  echo color 03
  echo :loop
  echo SET /A ip=ip+1
  echo ECHO IP No. %%ip%%
  echo SET /P website=Enter a website URL:
  echo ping %%website%% -l 8 -w 1 -n 1
  echo goto :loop
) >>"C:\Users\%user%\desktop\WebIPFind.bat"
```

Comment: how would i do this twice in one file?

Comment: @pleasehelpme It's already a bad idea to do it once, why do you want to repeat it? Why not just execute the code in the current batch file?

Comment: i want to repeat it because I want it to act as something that will install the files on a computer from a usb or a shared google drive. (I want to share the things i made with people)

Comment: @pleasehelpme Okay, you can simply move the code to be a function and call it twice, but you should modify the `WebIPFind.bat` filename then or append instead of overwrite the text